# Array to string conversion issue works before submitting form but not after

Tags: php

Hello I am having trouble with array to string conversion in the following script.

The problem is on the top if statement.  For some reason it works fine in the else statement underneath but I keep getting a array to string conversion error when submitting my form and I'm not sure why it works before submitting the form but not after.

The problem is apparently in the first

```
$content[] = array.
```

It just returns the word array for $video variable.  So where it states the videoid in data-videoID="" it just comes up as data-videoId="Array".  Everything esle comes up fine.  This would be on line 12 and 13.  Here is the code I am using. Im sure it probably something simple that I am overlooking because I am in no way as experienced with php as I probably should be.  I have looked over other posts and have tried taking off the brackets and several other things but still cant figure it out.  Like I said it works fine if I take out the if statement and just use the else statement.  Here is the code.

```
if(isset($_GET['q'])) {
$keyword_q = $_GET['q'];
$keyword = preg_replace('/\s+/', '/', $keyword_q);
$file = file_get_contents("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?videoEmbeddable=true&videoType=any&part=id%2Csnippet&q=$keyword&videoSyndicated=true&type=video&maxResults=50&key=$key");
$decoded = json_decode($file, true);  
$entries = $decoded['items'];  
if (!empty($entries)) {  
    for($i=0; $i<count($entries); $i++) {  
        $thumb = $entries[$i]['snippet']['thumbnails']['medium']['url'];  
        $videotitle = $entries[$i]['snippet']['title'];  
        $videodescription = $entries[$i]['snippet']['description'];  
        $video = $entries[$i]['id'];
        $content[] = "<li><a href='#' data-videoID='$video' class='video-link'><img src='$thumb' alt='Play Video'></a><h3 class='video-title'>$videotitle</h3><p class='video-description'>$videodescription</p></li>";
    }             
} 
$videos = ""; 
if (!empty($content)) {  
    foreach($content as $thumb){ 
        $videos .= "$thumb";  
    } 
} 
} 
else {
$filefeatured = file_get_contents("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?chart=mostPopular&part=snippet&maxResults=30&key=$key");  
$decoded = json_decode($filefeatured, true);  
$entries = $decoded['items'];  
if (!empty($entries)) {  
    for($i=0; $i<count($entries); $i++) {  
        $thumb = $entries[$i]['snippet']['thumbnails']['medium']['url'];  
        $videotitle = $entries[$i]['snippet']['title'];  
        $videodescription = $entries[$i]['snippet']['description'];  
        $video = $entries[$i]['id'];  
        $content[]= "<li><a href='#' data-videoID='$video' class='video-link'><img src='$thumb' alt='Play Video'></a><h3 class='video-title'>$videotitle</h3><p class='video-description'>$videodescription</p></li>";
    }             
} 
$videos = ""; 
if (!empty($content)) {  
    foreach($content as $thumb){ 
        $videos .= "$thumb";  
    } 
} 
}
```

Comment: Well, one of the variables `$thumb`, `$videotitle`, `$videodescription` or `$video` has got to be an array then.

Comment: I dont see a `$content[] = array.` but if I missed it it should be `$content = array();` or `$content = [];`

Comment: Please post the **exact error message** and indicate **which line that is** in your script. Otherwise this is just a guessing game and wasting our time as well as yours

Comment: The problem is that one of your variables on that line is an array and you're trying to use it as a string.  To start debugging, var_dump each variable defined in the for loop.

Comment: I have edited it at the top to include where the errors are occuring.  What happens is that just the $video is coming back as an array so in the source it comes up as data-videoID="Array"  but everything else like the images come back just fine and before the form is submitted everything works fine it us just after I submit the form just the $video comes back as an array

Comment: can you `var_dump($video )` and show us the results? or event better `var_dump($entries[$i])`

Comment: You are doing 2 different searches on youtube. The results of the searches is obviously slightly different and in the first search you get more than one video returned and it is returned in an array. So you need to amend how you process the results of your searches

Comment: Wow so I didn't even realize that the most popular and the search list ID sections come up differently when you call them.  So I just had to add the ['videoId'] to the $video variable when calling the search list  and its working fine now.  I can't believe I didn't think of that thanks I feel really stupid. Thanks a lot.